# User's position in Ruby on Rails, Devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to display a user's position on `show` page. For example, "Your position is 1921 out of 195119". Is there any effective way to do such thing in `devise gem`?

My idea was to add an extra column inside `users` table and make it auto increment for each entry. However, I think that there is a better way to do so. Thank you very much for your help and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your User models have number of records and those are stored with `id` which is already auto incremented. Adding `position` similar to `id` is useless.

You can achieve it by following as few of your records used to get deleted and you want position as per existing records.

```
@position = User.all.ids.sort.index(@user.id)
```

Here `@user` is object for which 'show' action is getting called to get `@position`

Comment: Thank you very much, couldn't find the right answer in Google.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a column for position you probably need to update it if some of the records are deleted.

You can do two count queries, given a `user` object.

```
count_1 = User.where("id <= ?", user.id).count
```

`count_1` is the position of the user

```
count_2 = User.count
```

`count_2` is the total postions

Comment: Thank you for the answer, really appreciate your help sir!